# Вместо пробела, вставляет другой символ

Tags: c++

Данный код шифрует шифром Виженера.
Подключаю в основную программу из dll библиотеки.

```
    String symbols="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i,j,c,sum;

    void Keycode(String s){

        for(int i=1;i<=symbols.Length();i++)
            if (s==symbols[i])
                c=i;
    }

extern "C" char* __declspec(dllexport) Viziner_shif(String key, String text)
{

    String result;

    for(i=1;i<=text.Length();i++){
        if(j>=key.Length())
            j=0;
        j++;
        Keycode(text[i]);
        sum=c;
        Keycode(key[j]);
        sum=sum+c;
        if(sum>118)
            sum=sum-118;
        result+=symbols[sum];
    }

    j=0;
    return AnsiString(result).c_str();

}

extern "C" char* __declspec(dllexport) Viziner_deshif(String key, String text)
{
    String result;

    for(i=1;i<=text.Length();i++)
    {
        if(j>=key.Length())
            j=0;
        j++;
        Keycode(text[i]);
        sum=c;
        Keycode(key[j]);
        sum=sum-c;
        if(sum<1)
            sum=sum+118;
        result+=symbols[sum];
    }
    j=0;
    return AnsiString(result).c_str();

}
```

Передача переменных `key` и `text` происходит из основной программы вот так...

```
// ENCRYPTION
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
      HINSTANCE DLL = LoadLibrary(_T("Dll.dll"));

       // исходный текст
        AnsiString textl = Edit3->Text;
        String text = System::String(textl.c_str());



        //ключ
        AnsiString keyl= Edit1->Text;
        String key = System::String(keyl.c_str());



   // Проверяем наличие DLL
    if (DLL)
    {
        // Обращаемся к функции
        Viziner_SH = (Viziner_shif *) GetProcAddress(DLL,"_Viziner_shif");
            if (Viziner_SH)
             {
                  string abc = Viziner_SH(key, text);
                  Memo1->Lines->Add(abc.c_str());
             }

            else ShowMessage("DLL not found!");


    }
    else
    {
        ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
        ShowMessage("Unable to load the DLL");
    }

   FreeLibrary(DLL);  // выгружаем DLL библиотеку
}
```

Происходит зашифровка: `"Stack Overflow"` c `key = П` -> `ИрYазHЕтвогилу`
Далее расшифровка: `"ИрYазHЕтвогилу"` c `key = П` -> `StackПOverflow`

Почему вместо пробела вставляется символ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В твоём словаре пробел никак не поддерживается, поэтому функция `Keycode` не меняет значение переменной `с` и оно остаётся равным значению с предыдущей итерации.

Чтобы этот шифр работал, на вход должны подаваться только известные символы. Поэтому тебе или надо добавить пробел, или убирать его из текста перед шифровкой. Лучше всего, думаю, добавить `+`в словарь, менять пробел на плюс перед шифрованием и обратно после шифрования.  В этом случае зашифрованная строка не будет разрываться пробелами

Comment: Что плохого в разрыве пробелами?

Comment: Особенности этого метода таковы, что при повреждении одного символа при расшифровке будет поврежден один символ - не беда. А вот если символ добавлен или потерян, то с этой позиции весь оставшийся текст превращается в тыкву. Теперь представь, что шифрованная строка содержит два или три пробела подряд или вообще начинается с пробела или нескольких? Для лабораторной работы может и без разницы, но в реальной жизни при рукописном шифровании это было бы трудно поддерживать. Поэтому в оригинальном варианте пробел не использовался.

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov - а можешь объяснить работу данных функций, хотя-бы поверхностно!?

Comment: Я твои функции и не смотрел вообщем-то. Я сначала почитал Википедию, что такое шифр Вижинера. Оказалось, вариация шифра Цезаря. Как и любой циклический сдвиг, он не поддерживает символы вне цикла - тут уже стало понятно, почему пробел неправильно шифруется. Осталось только понять, почему `П` выводится - ну тут уже я посмотрел `Keycode`.

Comment: В Википедии довольно понятно объяснено как он работает. 118 в твоём коде - это длина словаря (33+33+26+26). Если добавляешь в словарь `+`, то надо заменить на 119. Единственное отличие от википедии - у автора твоего кода операция `mod n` заменена на `if sum > n then sum -= n` и на `if sum < 1 then sum += n`